# What is the equivalent slack event to team_join when a user leaves (or is removed from) a team

Tags: events, slack, slack-api

Using the [Slack events API](https://api.slack.com/events), what is the equivalent event to [`team_join`](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join) for when a user leaves, or is removed from a team?

My app needs to know when users leave or are removed from a Slack team so it can deactivate them.

Answer (score 10):

So I asked Slack directly, and this is the response I got

https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1009365516367122433

> A `user_change` event will tell you when an account has been deactivated https://api.slack.com/events/user_change

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, looking at an example, the `user.deleted` property becomes `true` in the `user_change` event